# svn:the URL is not WebDAV-enabled

Tags: svn, webdav, visualsvn-server

Getting following error while using svn info command in command prompt,

```
 svn: E175003: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://myserver.svn.com/svn/MainDB'
 svn: E175003: The OPTIONS response did not include the requested activity-collection-set;
 this often means that the URL is not WebDAV-enabled
```

By using ip, we able to get the info result "svn info https://[server-ip]/svn/MainDB"..

The command i have tired is,
"C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\Bin\svn.exe" info "https://myserver.svn.com/svn/MainDB"

Note: I have used windows XP machine and installed VisualSVN Server 2.5.2. I don't have apache installed in my machine.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the hostname myserver.svn.com points not to VisualSVN Server, but to another service. Make sure that DNS settings are correct for the myserver.svn.com.

Comment: I have verified the DNS settings and its fine. Previously it was working with hostname... Now only it is not working. Any setup is missing ?